# Print the count of every occurence of the text in each row and column from the dataset

Tags: python, excel, count, xlrd, find-occurrences

I have the following image:
Please look at it for reference.

http://i58.tinypic.com/33219hh.png

What I am trying to get is for the code to read every value
in each column, and tell me how many times that "number" and 
"letter" is there in the column. In other words, what is the
occurrence of that "number" and "letter" in their respective columns?

Here is my code:

```
import xlrd,xlwt

ws = 'C://Users/Jack/Desktop

extract=[]
wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(ws + 'try.xlsx')
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)

for a in range(0,sh1.nrows):
    for b in range(0,sh1.ncols):
        extract.append(sh1.cell(a,b).value)
#print(extract)
print()
print('4:',extract.count('4'))
```

Output is `4: 0`

I am only trying to count the number 4 from the first column
because I do not know how to count everything from every
column at once. The output is supposed to read `4: 3`.
But, I want to know how to read everything at once as mentioned
earlier above.

Comment: you might want to look at `pandas.read_excel`

Comment: You could possibly use [```zip```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose the rows and columns then use [```collections.Counter```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to tally the results.  Or just use ```collections.Counter``` with the ```col```  attribute of the ```Sheet``` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary for each column:

```
for col in range(0,sh1.ncols):
    counts = {}
    for row in range(1, sh1.nrows): #start with 1 to skip header
        val = sh1.cell(row,col).value
        if val not in counts:
            counts[val] = 0
        counts[val] += 1
    extract.append(counts)

# to get the total number of 4s in the 1st column (index 0) run:
print "4:%d" % extract[0][4]
```

Comment: What do u want me to do with the old code. Delete what and keep what ?

Comment: Keep everything before your for loop.  And then replace your for loop with mine.

Comment: The answer comes out to 1 instead of 3 for the count of 4. Also, I want to do it for the complete dataset I have on that picture link.

Comment: Strange, are you sure you did "counts[val] += 1" instead of "counts[val] = 1"?  I checked using your dataset and it worked for me.  This will also work for the complete dataset.  extract[0][<number>] will show you the counts of any number and extract[1][<letter>] will show you the counts of any letter.

Comment: I want to display the count for every number in "numbers" and for every letter in "letters", and that also at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). The solution can be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.io.excel.read_excel(your_file_name)
print df.icol(0).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import xlrd,xlwt

def printDate(res):
    for k,v in sorted(res.items(),key = lambda (k,v):(v,k),reverse= True):
        print('{} : {}'.format(k,v))
    print()

ws = 'C:\Users\galaxyan\Desktop\\'
wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(ws + 'Book1.xlsx')
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)
letterRes, numRes = {},{}
for a in range(1,sh1.nrows):
    numValue = sh1.cell(a,0).value
    letterValue = sh1.cell(a,1).value
    numRes[numValue] = numRes.get(numValue,0) + 1
    letterRes[letterValue] = letterRes.get(letterValue,0) + 1

printDate(letterRes)
printDate(numRes)
```

output:

```
B : 4
E : 3
D : 3
A : 3
C : 1

3.0 : 4
5.0 : 3
4.0 : 3
2.0 : 2
1.0 : 2
```

Comment: Yes. That is correct.That does fix my problem for printing the count for 4. But, my original question is to do the same thing for the whole dataset I have. How can I do that ?

Comment: res is dict and stores all the frequency

Comment: Awesome!! But, I am getting an error.                                                                   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-4a5beebd8147> in <module>()
     13     res[letterValue] = res.get(letterValue,0) + 1
     14 
---> 15 for k,v in res.iteritems():
     16     print('{} : {}'.format(k,v))

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: try again. I think you are using python 3

Comment: Still an error. Yes. I am using python 3. Also, I would also want the output to be arranged. The "numbers" should be all together in the column when printed, and the "letters" should be all together.

Comment: you could sort the key of dict then use sorted key to find the value

Comment: Now a new error.        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-fb8b83a48ea0> in <module>()
      9     res[letterValue] = res.get(letterValue,0) + 1
     10 
---> 11 sortedKey= sorted(res.keys())
     12 for k in sortedKey:
     13     print('{} : {}'.format(k,res[k]))

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()

Comment: Idk why, but you could convert all the keys of dict to str then sort

Comment: I honestly do not know what that means. Please, help me get this to work. You have already a lot and appreciate that.

Comment: I got it to work. Last thing. I still want those titles to print. So, "numbers" should print above the numbers, and "letters" over letters with a space in between numbers and letters.

Comment: There should be the word "Numbers" above 1.0 : 2, 2.0 : 2, and so on.

Comment: Also, can the letter or number with the highest count be at the top, and then the smaller number than that goes below it, and so on , and then the lowest count number is at the bottom. So, in our case for "Numbers" , 3.0: 4 should be at the top, then 4.0 & 5.0, and at the end 1.0 and 2.0. And, if i add more columns then?

Comment: File "<ipython-input-41-94a711a8b425>", line 2
    for k,v in sorted(res.items(),key = lambda(k,v):(v,k),reverse= True):
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: it works for me, but i am using python 2. To sort the dict may be different in those two version.

Comment: Any alternative solution?

Comment: Please help me out here. This is the last thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Feed each column to [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
import collections, xlrd
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
columns = []
for i in xrange(sh.ncols):
    columns.append(collections.Counter(sh.col_values(i)))

format_str = 'column {}: {}'
for n, column in enumerate(columns):
    print(format_str.format(n, column))
>>> 
column 0: Counter({u'a': 3, u'b': 2, u'c': 1, u'd': 1})
column 1: Counter({u'c': 2, u'b': 2, u'd': 2, u'a': 1})
column 2: Counter({u'c': 4, u'a': 1, u'b': 1, u'd': 1})
>>>
```